# sources.list: vs-bionic vs stable-bionic

Tags: software-sources

When looking at the [mono installation instructions for Ubuntu](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/) I see they use `vs-bionic main` instead of `stable-bionic main` that I've seen elsewhere.

Doing a search for "vs-bionic" is not revealing anything I can find.

What's the difference?

Comment: That's for MonoDevelop the IDE. Mono is over at https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

Comment: ahhh thanks for that, I didn't notice the breadcrumbs/options at the top. That makes it clear now. If you want to throw that into an answer, I can accept it

Comment: I haven't really taken the trouble to understand it. It'd be better if you posted what you understood as an answer. (Also, perhaps you still haven't noticed: my comment's link and your post's link are from different sites.)

Comment: I will, no probs.  I didn't initially notice. It took a bit because I noticed the breadcrumbs on your link but when I went back to the other tab I saw they weren't there. It did have me stumped for a moment. I have two projects open and one is under monidevelop. I hadn't realised I was on two different websites. It's much clearer now. Thanks.